# Fazer um Locate de um ClientDataSet é muito custoso?

Tags: delphi

Fazer um `locate` de um `dataset` ligado ao banco, certamente é bastante custoso. Mas fazer um `locate` num `dataset` com **dados apenas em memória**, é uma boa prática? Ou seria melhor criar um `array`?

Grato.

Comment: Já cogitou a possibilidade de utilizar um `TDictionary` ?

Comment: @VictorZanella  Não, podes dar mais detalhes sobre o funcionamento de `TDictionary`?

Comment: só para confirmar, qual versão do Delphi você está utilizando ?

Comment: @VictorZanella Delphi XE7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segue um exemplo simples de utilização do Dictionary.

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs,
  System.Generics.Collections, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type

  TPessoa = class
    id: integer;
    nome: string;
    sobrenome: string;
    idade: integer;
    sexo: string;
  end;

  TListaPessoa = TObjectList<TPessoa>;

  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    btnBuscarPessoa: TButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnBuscarPessoaClick(Sender: TObject);

  private
    FListaPessoa: TListaPessoa;
    FDicionarioPessoa: TDictionary<integer, TPessoa>;

    procedure AdicionarPessoas;
    procedure AlimentarDicionario;

  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

uses
  StrUtils;

{$R *.dfm}




procedure TForm2.AdicionarPessoas;
var
  i: integer;
begin

  for i := 1 to 10000 do
  begin

    FListaPessoa.Add(TPessoa.Create);
    FListaPessoa.Last.id        := i;
    FListaPessoa.Last.nome      := 'Nome' + IntToStr(Random(1000));
    FListaPessoa.Last.sobrenome := 'Sobrenome' + IntToStr(Random(1000));
    FListaPessoa.Last.idade     := Random(80);
    FListaPessoa.Last.sexo      := IfThen(odd(FListaPessoa.Last.id + FListaPessoa.Last.idade), 'M', 'F');

  end;

end;



procedure TForm2.AlimentarDicionario;
var
  FPessoa: TPessoa;
begin
  for FPessoa in FListaPessoa do
    if (not(FDicionarioPessoa.ContainsKey(FPessoa.id))) then
      FDicionarioPessoa.Add(FPessoa.id, FPessoa);
end;



procedure TForm2.FormCreate(
  Sender:
  TObject);
begin
  FListaPessoa      := TListaPessoa.Create;
  FDicionarioPessoa := TDictionary<integer, TPessoa>.Create;

  AdicionarPessoas;
  AlimentarDicionario;

end;



procedure TForm2.btnBuscarPessoaClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  identificador: integer;
begin

  identificador := Random(10000);

  ShowMessage(
    'A pessoca com o id ' + IntToStr(identificador) + ' é ' + FDicionarioPessoa.Items[identificador].nome + ' ' + FDicionarioPessoa.Items[identificador].sobrenome +
    ' tem ' + IntToStr(FDicionarioPessoa.Items[identificador].idade) + ' anos de idade e é do sexo ' +
    IfThen(FDicionarioPessoa.Items[identificador].sexo = 'M', 'masculino', 'feminino')

    );

end;

end.
```

Note que os métodos legais do Dictionary são os `ContainsKey` ou `ContainsValue`.

Obs.: No teste que fiz, coloquei 7000000 registros, e a busca é instantânea.

Obs2.:A ordenação dos dados também é rápida com Dicionario de dados.

Comment: Muito obrigado e parabéns pelo exemplo, bem detalhado e prático! @Victor Zanella

Comment: aaah, esqueci de avisar, mas as classes poderiam ser interfaces. Nesse caso eu esqueci de liberar os objetos criados.

Answer (score 1):

---

É mais custoso em processamento. Principalmente porque a cada nova execução de locate, você teria que posicionar o registro no início do DataSet.

Uma opção melhor seria você utilizar o FindKey([]).

Para utilizá-lo, você precisa apenas configurar e utilizar um índice no DataSet e utilizar os campos no FindKey.

Ex:

```
cdsDataSet.IndexDefs.add('IDX_NOME','CAMPO1;CAMPO2;CAMPO3',[]);
cdsDataSet.IndexName := 'IDX_NOME';

// Observe que você não precisa passar todos os campos do índice
// Mas precisa seguir sempre a mesma ordem.

if cdsDataSet.FindKey([_valorCampo1, _valorCampo2]) then
  showMessage('Achei')
else
  ShowMessage('não achei');
```