# Como receber System.Generics.Collections.TList em um TList?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

Estou com um problema ao tentar pegar a TList de uma Generics.Collections.TList.

Dá o seguinte erro:

```
[dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(101): E2010 Incompatible types: 'TExame' and 'System.Generics.Collections.TList<modExame.TExame>'
```

Basicamente recebo de um Json para a classe, mas não consigo acessar uma classe dentro dessa classe. Pois é em 'Clientes.Exames.Exame', dentro de Clientes, tem a TExame que quero pegar os valores mas dá incompatibilidade

Comment: Como você deserializa esse JSON? Como você está atribuindo valor a sua lista genérica?

Comment: Respondi uma questão onde mostrei como usar listas genericas. Vê se te ajuda.http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/155969/fazer-um-locate-de-um-clientdataset-%C3%A9-muito-custoso/156317#156317